# What is the meaning of "girth" of a rectangular box?

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization

Here's an optimization problem.

> A parcel delivery service will deliver a package only if the length plus the girth (distance around, taken perpendicular to the length) does not exceed 112 inches. Find the maximum volume of a rectangular box with square ends that satisfies the delivery company's requirements.

I have a few issues with it, but mainly I don't know what the "girth" of the box is. I think I have a general idea of what to do after I learn what that is.

Comment: Girth is also the perimeter of the cross section. It is like taking a knife through the box and measuring the perimeter of the resulting rectangle.

Comment: @Sumo so...with regards to length width and height, what is less than or equal 112 inches?

Comment: Traditional word for post office, airline luggage size requirements and so on. If the ends of your long box are square, it is the perimeter of the square. Not entirely sure an airline uses the word the same way...

Comment: @willjagy oh, I see. Since $P=4s$, then $4s<112$. Thanks!

Comment: It is related to words such as girdle, and phrases from warfare in literature such as "gird your loins." The original meaning for humans (girdle) was what we now call a man's belt, just a loop to keep up your pants, the girth being the length of the belt in use, waist size. I found similar use with horses, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girth_%28tack%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us say we have a box. We know that the volume is $l \cdot w \cdot h$.We know that we are trying to optimize this problem with the constraint that $2 w+2 h+l$ is $112$. We know that the base is a square so the volume is now $l^2 h$. We also happen to know that $w=h$. So we have $4w+l=112$. We can isolate the constraint as such: $l=112-4w$. We then get this cubic $(112-4w)^2 \cdot w$. I am sure that you can do the rest.